# How to use certain implementation of interface in code

Tags: php, oop

how can I use certain implementation of interface in code to fast access it's parameters? should I use doctype to hint IDE?
Code below throws

```
Declaration of Cook::handle(CookingList $j) must be compatible with Action::handle(Lists $l)
```

```php
interface Lists {
    
}   

class CookingList implements Lists {
    
}
    
interface Action {
    public function handle(Lists $l);
}    
              
class Cook implements Action {
    public function handle(CookingList $j) {
        
    }
}

$mylist = new CookingList();
$job = new Cook();
$job->handle($mylist);
```